# ConvergenceError: Convergence halted due to matrix inversion problems

Tags: python, cox-regression, survival, lifelines

I keep having error messages anytime I try running CoxPH regression in Python. I'm not a pro in python still learning.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter
from lifelines.statistics import multivariate_logrank_test   
from lifelines.statistics import logrank_test
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter
import pyreadstat
```

After loading the data

```
data["faculty2"] = data["faculty2"].astype(int)
data["sex"] = data["sex"].astype(int)
data["mos"] = data["mos"].astype(int)
data["state2"] = data["state2"].astype(int)
data["ss"] = data["ss"].astype(int)
data["supervisor"] = data["supervisor"].astype(int)
data["time"] = data["time"].astype(int)
data["event"] = data["event"].astype(int)

Eventvar = data['event']
Timevar = data['time']

""" assigning labels to values"""
data['sex'] = data['sex'].apply({1:'Male', 0:'female'}.get)
data['faculty2'] = data['faculty2'].apply({1:'Arts',2:'Sciences',3:'Medicals',\
                                            4:'Agriculture', 5:'Social Sciences',6:'Education',\
                                                7:'Tech',8:'Law',9:'Institues'}.get)
data['state2'] = data['state2'].apply({1:'SW',2:'SS',3:'SE',4:'NC', 5:'NE',6:'NW'}.get)
data['ss'] = data['ss'].apply({1:'Yes', 0:'No'}.get)
data['mos'] = data['mos'].apply({1:'Full Time', 0:'Part Time'}.get)

cf = CoxPHFitter()
cf.fit(data, 'time', event_col='event',show_progress=True)
cf.print_summary()
```

I get this error message when i run these codes

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Arts'
```

Please I need help I don't know how to go about this
If I add dummies i have a different error message

```
ohe_features = ['faculty2', 'sex', 'mos','state2','ss'] 
data = pd.get_dummies(data,drop_first=True,columns=ohe_features)
```

This is the error message I get

```
ConvergenceError: Convergence halted due to matrix inversion problems. Suspicion is high collinearity. Please see the following tips in the lifelines documentation: https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html#problems-with-convergence-in-the-cox-proportional-hazard-modelMatrix is singular
```

If i run the codes without **assigning values to labels** and without adding **dummies** it runs but the different levels are not showing. It runs as though it were continuous variables

[Here is the data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3etw1n69kfdwqlz/data.csv?dl=0)

Comment: If I add dummies i have a different error message `ohe_features = ['faculty2', 'sex', 'mos','state2','ss']
data = pd.get_dummies(data,drop_first=True,columns=ohe_features)`

Comment: This is the error message I get `ConvergenceError: Convergence halted due to matrix inversion problems. Suspicion is high collinearity. Please see the following tips in the lifelines documentation: https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html#problems-with-convergence-in-the-cox-proportional-hazard-modelMatrix is singular.`

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional information, it's easier to read there than in the comments.

Comment: If i run the codes without **assigning values to labels** and without adding *dummies* it runs but the different levels are not showing. It runs as though it were continuous variables

Comment: If you are getting warnings about high collinearity, it sounds like your independent variables are too correlated with each other for the algorithm to converge to a meaningful solution. That's more a numerical problem than a programming problem. The ValueError looked like a syntax problem in your data frame however. Without knowing your data this one could be tough to diagnose in the SO format.

Comment: I can attach the data if needed

Comment: I don't have the time to troubleshoot it, this is why I am just making suggestions via comment.

Comment: @Soloibom without the data it's hard to debug. Can you attach / link to it?

Answer (score 1):

In the lifelines documentation they suggest

1. Add the penalize parameter
2. Use the variance inflation factor or
3. check the correlation matrix in your dataset

https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html#problems-with-convergence-in-the-cox-proportional-hazard-modelMatrix

Answer (score 0):

I had the pretty identical problem. I changed

cph = CoxPHFitter()

to

cph = CoxPHFitter(penalizer=0.0001)

This solved the issue.